# Vue App structuring

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am currently trying to build my first webapp using vue.js

Now 2 days of tutorials deep I am still not 100% sure how to structure a basic application.
Using the vue-cli and webpack already makes a nice structure, including a /src Folder with components and a /router Folder for routing.

Now my plan is to create a ToDo App. I want to dynamically switch between [show todos] and [add todo], which is just a form with a submit button.
I have already achieved it by using it without components and the cli.

My structure would be:

***App.vue*** -> buttons with the two `router-link` to components/ShowTodos.vue & components/AddTodos.vue

***components/ShowTodos.vue*** -> Table including the todo list

***components/AddTodos.vue*** -> Form with submit button

Now the routing part works, I am able to switch between those two components.

Now 2 Questions:

1. How can I push the information from the form in the AddTodos component into an Array in the ShowTodos component in order to loop through there ?
2. Is this a proper way to structure an vue app, and if not how can I improve it ?

   Thank you very much.

This is the first time for me using a component based JS Framework, so its pretty hard to follow along.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On structuring your vuejs application , this can be helpful

```
app/
   moduleA/
      components/
      index.js
      routes.js
   moduleB/
      components/
      index.js
      routes.js
   index.js
   routers.js
   main.vue
   router/
   components/ -> shared
   main.js

// app/routes.js
import { routes as moduleA } from './moduleA'
import { routes as moduleB } from './moduleB'
export default [ ...moduleA, ...moduleB ]

// app/moduleA/index.js
export { default as routes } from './routes'

// app/moduleB/index.js
export { default as routes } from './routes'

// app/index.js
export { default as routes } from './routes
```

'

Answer (score 1):

About the second question, I did some researches, and that's what I recommend:

```
.
├── app.css
├── App.vue
├── assets
│   └── ...
├── components
│   └── ...
├── main.js
├── mixins
│   └── ...
├── router
│   └── index.js
├── store
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── modules
│   │   └── ...
│   └── mutation-types.js
├── translations
│   └── index.js
├── utils
│   └── ...
└── views
    └── ...
```

Read more here: https://medium.com/@sandoche/how-to-structure-a-vue-js-project-eabe75161882

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this [boilerplate](https://github.com/petervmeijgaard/vue-2.0-boilerplate). It has a very good structure and I am now using it in every project.

```
/components
/layouts
/mixins
/pages
/routes
/services
/store
/transformers
```

He also explains the structure very well. https://github.com/petervmeijgaard/vue-2.0-boilerplate#structure